# How can I get a list up until the last occurrence of an element from a list?

Tags: scheme, r5rs

I'm using scheme R5RS.

Given a list with multiple entries, I would like to return that list up until the last occurrence of a given element.

So for the following input:

A list `'("hi" "how" "are" "you")`
Keyword `"you"`

I want the following output:
A list `'("hi" "how" "are")`

I couldn't find a function in scheme R5RS with this capability but maybe I am missing something.  If such a function doesn't exist, how would I implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little trickier than it seems at first sight, but this should work:

```
(define (last lst key)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((member key (cdr lst))
         (cons (car lst) (last (cdr lst) key)))
        (else '())))
```

The key insight is that you should use `member` to check if the element is still present in the list (that will tell us when we've found its last occurrence). Also you should consider two special cases - what happens if the list is empty, or if the key is not in the list? In both cases I'm returning an empty list. For example:

```
(last '("hi" "how" "are" "you") "you")
=> '("hi" "how" "are")

(last '("hi" "how" "are" "how" "you") "how")
=> '("hi" "how" "are")

(last '("hi" "how" "are" "how" "you") "today")
=> '()

(last '() "empty")
=> '()
```

Comment: Great! it was my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite succintly if you reverse the list and then look for the *first* occurence:

```
(define (last lst key)
  (define r (member key (reverse lst)))
  (if r 
      (reverse (cdr r))
      '()))
```